# What's the best way to add schema FAQ markup to a WordPress site without using a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, google-rich-snippets, structured-data, rich-snippets

If it requires a lot of technical WP knowledge, I'd consider a light plugin, but prefer to not add yet another one to the list...

Comment: see [this example](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was add the JSON-LD FAQ Schema Code to the top of the page in my Wordpress editor and it works according to the Structured Data Testing Tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can add raw html including structured data (microdata or json-ld) via the Custom HTML block.

There are several websites out there that can help you build that structured data.

Answer (score 0):

Once you understand the logic for the FAQ schema code, its easy to add the raw HTML and also to reuse for multiple applications. In my experience, that's a fair advantage over the weight/possible conflicts of a plugin.

[image: Google Search Console Report for one site]

Search Appearance   Clicks  Impressions
FAQ rich results    3,503   547,689